# Object containing list of Strings

Tags: java

I have a class that has two lists of Strings.

```
public class School {
private List<String> students;
private List<String> teachers;
//getters and setters
}
```

I have the below method in my DAO class where the school object is getting populated.

```
public static School fetchSchoolInfo(String schoolName) throws SQLException
{       
    School school = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<String>();        
    try {
        connection = createConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COL_STUDENT,COL_TEACHERS FROM SCHOOL WHERE SCHOOLNAME=?");
        statement.setString(1, schoolName);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            school = new School();                              
            students.add(rs.getString(1));
            teachers.add(rs.getString(1));
            school.setStudents(students);
            school.setTeachers(teachers);               
        }                       
    } finally{
        rs.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }

    return school;
}
```

Now, if I do this,

```
School school = MyDAO.fetchPersonDeviceIdInfo("SJSU");
System.out.println(school);
```

Will the school object have all the info of SJSU? I know I can ideally try this on my own and check, but my application is very complex, and it will take a while to integrate this code with my application. Please suggest. Also, do I need a to string?

Many thanks!

Comment: COL_TEACHERS is second column, so you need  `teachers.add(rs.getString(2));`.  `school = new School()` should be before the while loop,and `school.setStudents()` and `school.setTeachers()` should be after the while loop.  You might also want to check if your connection, statement, result set objects are null before trying to close them.

Comment: teachers.add(rs.getString(1)); should be teachers.add(rs.getString(2));

Comment: The answer actually depend on the table structure. Please post those details.

Comment: Sorry, I typed my code on this page. So I got it wrong. I actually have it as 2 :)

Comment: @Thihara - The table has School information. It has multiple columns that I don't feel comfortable posting here. The columns include teachers, students, teacher address, student contact information etc. What I am trying to find it, for each school, what are the list of students, and teachers. Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the following :

```
while(rs.next())
    {
        school = new School();                              
        students.add(rs.getString(1));
        teachers.add(rs.getString(1));
        school.setStudents(students);
        school.setTeachers(teachers);               
    }
```

to

```
school = new School(); 
while(rs.next())
    {

        students.add(rs.getString(1));
        teachers.add(rs.getString(2)); // changed

    }  

school.setStudents(students);
school.setTeachers(teachers);
```

Comment: Change `teachers.add(rs.getString(1));` to  `teachers.add(rs.getString(2));`

Comment: Sure. What is the difference between instantiating the object in the while loop vs outside. I've seen a few examples online where they instantiate inside so for each row in the resultset, a new object gets created so the object has all the records, and not just the last ones. Can you please explain the difference?

Comment: when u instantiate it inside the loop say u have four records, each time a new school obj will be created, and the last one will be overwritten @rickygrimes

Comment: if it were a list of school objects then in that case, instantiating school inside wud have worked, where at the end you could add school to the list. :)..

Comment: Okay guys, thank you so much. You guys are awesome :) I hope to become like one of you :)

Comment: @rickygrimes Happy to help..!! All the best.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Override your `School.toString()` method like this

```
class School {
  private List<String> students;
  private List<String> teachers;
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "School [students=" + students + ", teachers=" + teachers + "]";
  } 
}
```

Then you try

```
School school = MyDAO.fetchPersonDeviceIdInfo("SJSU");
System.out.println(school);
```

Comment: Sure. Thank you ByteCode. I just wanted to make sure if overriding is needed.